# DataStax Cloud Copy Local files

Tags: copy, datastax

I am unable to copy my local files to datastax cloud Database.If anyone knows Please help me out.

I want to copy my .csv files to Datastax Cloud Database.And want to get all copied items by using SELECT*FROM table Command.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question @Diwakar. There is a dedicated tool named [DataStax Bulk Loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkAbout.html) that is developed to perform `count`, `load` and `unload` operations into your DataStax Astra DB cluster. Please see all [the various examples here](https://www.datastax.com/search?query=datastax+bulk+loader&dataset=blog) for doing such operations.