# APACHE CASSANDRA DATASTAX

Tags: cassandra, copy, datastax, cql

WANT TO COPY MY LOCAL FILES TO APACHE CASSANDRA CQL CONSOLE.

TRIED TO COPY THE LOCAL FILES BY USING ($ dsbulk load -url E:\svit\Apache cassandra\Learning Apache Cassandra - Working\event.csv -header true -k location_tracker -t activity1 -b "E:\svit\Apache\secure-connect-myfirstdb.zip" -u lXDfRWJZSDwbUOhtsZF -p 4wW3,WobXX3DXWuChs3T4PW071.AYLa65b8H68ZwyoPZzAnl4uAv1yZ9vpabyc79zTTtZ5,gUhPm_WMGIeIeZU3UmyHmqv0t+GIAqEeoe5iFM03h0) COMMAND and got (

````
Invalid syntax at char 1
  $ dsbulk load -url E:\svit\Apache cassandra\Learning Apache Cassandra - Working\event.csv -header true -k location_tracker -t activity1 -b "E:\svit\Apache\secure-connect-myfirstdb.zip" -u lXDfRWJZSDwbUOhtsZF -p 4wW3,WobXX3DXWuChs3T4PW071.AYLa65b8H68ZwyoPZzAnl4uAv1yZ9vpabyc79zTTtZ5,gUhPm_WMGIeIeZU3UmyHmqv0t+GIAqEeoe5iFM03h0```
)ERROR.I WAS EXPECTING TO GET THE DATA OF EVENT.CSV TABLE ON MY CONSOLE.
````

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in here? The ask is not very clear. I have already provided [you directions to leverage DSBulk to load your CSV files into the Cassandra table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74405806/10410162). Could you update your question to provide a couple lines of contents of your input CSV file, along with table schema and what you want to achieve to better help you? The subject of the question and contents of the details needs to be updated for better clarity of the question here.

Answer (score 0):

First, to see if you've properly downloaded **[DataStax Bulk Loader (aka DSBulk in short)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkAbout.html)** from https://downloads.datastax.com/#bulk-loader website, could you provide the output of the below command?

```
./dsbulk --version
```

It'd show something like as follows:

```
% ./dsbulk --version
DataStax Bulk Loader v1.10.0
```

The documentation for leveraging DSBulk to load data into your Astra DB cluster is available [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/getting-started/gs-dsbulk.html).

It *appears* from your command that you're trying to load data from your Windows machine over to Astra DB. Is that correct?

I'm going to try and provide a command based on your input to help you out here by using the full-form options.

```
./dsbulk load \
--dsbulk.schema.keyspace location_tracker \
--dsbulk.schema.table activity1 \
--datastax-java-driver.advanced.auth-provider.username lXDfRWJZSDwbUOhtsZF \
--datastax-java-driver.advanced.auth-provider.password '4wW3,WobXX3DXWuChs3T4PW071.AYLa65b8H68ZwyoPZzAnl4uAv1yZ9vpabyc79zTTtZ5,gUhPm_WMGIeIeZU3UmyHmqv0t+GIAqEeoe5iFM03h0' \
--datastax-java-driver.basic.cloud.secure-connect-bundle 'E:\svit\Apache\secure-connect-myfirstdb.zip' \
--dsbulk.connector.csv.url 'E:\svit\Apache cassandra\Learning Apache Cassandra - Working\event.csv' \
--dsbulk.connector.csv.header true
```

Since your path has spaces in between and also the `Client Secret` contains special characters, we're wrapping them in between the single quotes (`'`).

---

**Bonus**: If you going to leverage the same configuration properties, it is better to leverage the configuration file option with DSBulk as it'll be very convinient. See [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkLoadConfigFile.html) for additional details.

For example, I'll configure my credentials and [secure connect bundle](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/connect/secure-connect-bundle.html) inside the configuration file and pass in the remaining as command-line arguments to DSBulk.

Assuming I'm storing it at `/path/to/dsbulk.conf`, my configuration file in that case would look like:

```
datastax-java-driver {
  advanced {
    auth-provider {
      username = lXDfRWJZSDwbUOhtsZF
      password = "4wW3,WobXX3DXWuChs3T4PW071.AYLa65b8H68ZwyoPZzAnl4uAv1yZ9vpabyc79zTTtZ5,gUhPm_WMGIeIeZU3UmyHmqv0t+GIAqEeoe5iFM03h0"
    }
  }
  basic.cloud.secure-connect-bundle = "E:\svit\Apache\secure-connect-myfirstdb.zip"
}
dsbulk {
  connector {
    csv {
      header = true
    }
  }
}
```

and my command to load the input file will become simpler like:

```
./dsbulk load \
-f "/path/to/dsbulk.conf" \
--dsbulk.schema.keyspace location_tracker \
--dsbulk.schema.table activity1 \
--dsbulk.connector.csv.url 'E:\svit\Apache cassandra\Learning Apache Cassandra - Working\event.csv'
```